# Is there a way to get a mouseover event for a column header in tabulator?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I don't see a mouseover event for column header and it doesn't seem to fire row mouseover or cell mouseover (which makes sense).
Thanks.
-jpr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in option for mouseover event handling for column headers in Tabulator.

The [Column Callbacks Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/callbacks#column) contains a full list of available callbacks.

That being said, you could use a custom column header title formatter to add the callback yourself:

```js
var customTitleFormatter = function(cell){

    var headerEl = cell.getElement().parentNode.parentNode; //get the column header element from above the title element

    headerEl.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
        //do something
    });

    return cell.getValue(); // ensure the title is set on the cell
}
```

then in the column definition assigns it to a column

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", titleFormatter:customTitleFormatter}
```

Comment: Thanks, Oli!  Love using Tabulator for my project.

Comment: Oli,  getElement() works great there, but parentNode (and parentElement) are always null.  I see the elements in inspect.  Are they not attached to the dom yet for some reason?  Thanks.

Comment: Ahh yes, you may need to add a setTimeout of about 100ms before getting the parent and the column header might not have been added to the son when that function is called

Comment: That worked.  Any ideas about getting the column information on those events?  cell.getColumn does not exist.  I could search for the cell value in the column configuration, but just wondering if you have any other idea.